# SI units for sheet resistance using siunitx

Tags: siunitx

I'm trying to get the package `siunitx` to output the units for sheet resistance (Ohm per square), with the square as a square box. My current solution (in text mode) is:

```
30-60 $\Omega/\square$
```

Which works, but I prefer to have it rendered using the `\SI` command, for code consistency. My closest approach within the `SIunitx` commands is

```
\SIrange{30}{60}{\Ohm/sq}
```

This doesn't output the box, but rather the letters `sq`. Simply using `\square` fails, since that is already defined as longhand for `^2`. Is there any way to output the square symbol within `SIunitx`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Following works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}
\DeclareSIUnit\sq{\ensuremath{\Box}}
\begin{document}
\SIrange{30}{60}{\ohm\per\sq} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also customize the way in which the range is written using `range-phrase = --` and `range-units=single` as in this code sample:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}
\DeclareSIUnit\sq{\ensuremath\Box}
\begin{document}
\SIrange{30}{60}{\ohm\per\sq}


\SIrange[range-phrase = --,range-units=single]{30}{60}{\ohm\per\sq}

\SIrange[range-phrase = --,range-units=brackets]{30}{60}{\ohm\per\sq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd use `\ensuremath` in the definition, for safety

Comment: Only the fist and third examples are correct.  See <https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/pdf/sp811.pdf> Page v (7)